# Automatically fill in table based on count of cells that meet specific criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to set up a table which is to be filled in with the word "Credit" based on the number of courses taken by an individual that apply (are from the English category).

In my [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QdsgwLiQrGU7Q2ySI5e5t3WZTpxfn86XDqyA4adkR68/edit#gid=2127433474), the list on the left represents the courses taken by an individual, with the table at the top used as a reference as to which courses will satisfy with the English requirement.

Is it possible to fill in the table with the word "Credit" based on the number of matches found in the list of courses completed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional statements to test for those values and tally them

In your example, the Code:

`=IF(OR(A3 = $D$3, A3 = $D$4, A3 = $D$5, A3 = $D$6, A3 = $D$8), 1, 0)`

I've placed this code in column B in cell B3. I can than click and drag on the plus sign to fill the cells below it adjacent to all of the A column entries and it will test them against the values referenced in your D column.
I could put these functions anywhere in my workbook I wanted, but since your B column is empty, it makes it easy for me visually to verify that we have a 1 where we should and a zero where we should. Then you can auto-sum the column and voila, your number of English credits, which you can use for whatever you wish. If you really want to have all of the duplicate words in your table, you can skip the ones and zeros and put:

`=IF(OR(A3 = $D$3, A3 = $D$4, A3 = $D$5, A3 = $D$6, A3 = $D$8), "Credit", "")`

Directly into your table (changing A3 to A4, A5, etc. as needed).
Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much.  That will give me the count I need.  Is there any way for, based on the number in that count, to populate the blue table with the word "Credit" based on the number of times it shows up in the column (to make the top blue table look like the bottom blue table)?

Comment: Bardo - There are plenty of ways to do this. For example, in the first cell you want to say "Credit", enter =IF(B9 = 1, "Credit", ""). I just picked B9 as an example of where the sum of your credits may be. Enter in the actual value of yours in the formula. Then for your next cell: IF(B9 = 2, "Credit", ""), and so on until your maximum. That's all there is to it. However, you could also make an *actual* chart of it pretty easily as well, that would look so much better.